# Apache virtual server sub-site configuration

Tags: apache, config

I have been running a co-located Linux box with several httpd vhosts. A few years ago I recovered an archived web site and added it to an existing domain as a directory under htdocs as a sub-site. It is an older site that uses frames but works correctly underneath the main domain.

The old website has nostalgic value to certain hobbyists and a couple of weeks ago I decided to acquire another domain so that this sub-site could be accessed directly. However, the frames do not get set up correctly and the pages do not display like they should - stuff is obviously missing.

I have tried several things but no avail. Currently both domains point to the same location.

Here is my Apache config for the main site (http://www.vintagewargamingfigures.info/):

```
<VirtualHost 64.182.125.197:80>
    ServerName www.vintagewargamingfigures.info
    ServerAlias vintagewargamingfigures.info
    DocumentRoot /local/web_sites/vintage/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the config for the sub-site when it fails (http://www.vintage20mil.com/):

```
<VirtualHost 64.182.125.197:80>
    ServerName www.vintage20mil.com
    ServerAlias vintage20mil.com
    DocumentRoot /local/web_sites/vintage/htdocs/rblack
</VirtualHost>
```

The document root shows the site as being in a directory (rblack) under the main site.

Google Chrome has fooled me a couple of times and it looks like it was working but sometime later it will not work. So, I also use MS Edge to test it.

I have tried several things, including running some symbolic links directly to the rblack directory but haven't found the cure yet.

What am I missing? I suspect it is something simple but it is eluding me.

Any help appreciated.
.......CG